# Why are the Visual Studio executables inside a folder called 'Common7' instead of say Common10 or just Common?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

This is not the most important question in the world but I would like to know exactly why the Common7 is named this way and not incremented with releases. Is this like the Windows 7/8 version number issues (ie Windows 8 is version 6.2)?

The folder in question (with VS2010) is usually located in either:

`%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\`
or
%`programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first .NET version of Visual Studio was internal version 7.0, so I think they named the folder Common7 based on that. Then later there were a lot of dependencies (probably external, like plugins or whatnot) that used the name Common7 so it would break too much if they changed it in later version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although Hans goes into some detail I will award you the answer as you summed it up quickly. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

There are too many add-ins and build scripts that have hard-coded the "Common7" folder name.  Somewhat self-inflicted, it isn't that easy to find the proper path to the folder.  The environment variable name is VS90COMNTOOLS for VS2008.  Note the version number in the name, also not sure if it was available back in VS2003.